# How to fix self-intersecting geometry for 3D Printing?

Tags: modifiers, 3d-printing

My professor wants to do 3D printing, and here is the model he made
[image]

and each individual even intersect its mesh
[image]

I can't make links cause every mesh is at 0.0.0 location.

He demanded me to do a clean boolean so that printing is possible.
Is this task possible ?? I need your guys intelligence

Comment: select the hand in edit mode -> separate by selection -> add a boolean modifier to the body -> set it to difference and select the hand object as the target. Then apply the boolean modifier and if want you may join or merge vertices with the body

Comment: Drag it into Pruserslicer and try to slice it, it's surprising just how much that software can fix

Comment: I would ctrl+J everything and voxel remesh the whole thing to make it one solid object. Easy and will work 100% I use it to print complicated models made out of many parts all the time. Voxel remesh will make it really dense geometry so I recomend decimate modifier after the process.